# css - sometimes when hover on elements it be transperent even its not define

Tags: html, css, sass, zurb-foundation

I use a class named "save-button" to degsin buttons  in some page its work perfect in other when hover on it button disapear !!

this is the class in SCSS page (i use foundation frame work):

```css
    .save-button,.comment-button
{
background: url('../lib/foundation-sites/bower_components/foundation-sites/assets/images/comment_save.png');
}

.exit-button,
{
background: url('../lib/foundation-sites/bower_components/foundation-sites/assets/images/chose_file.gif');

}
.login-button
{
  background: url('../lib/foundation-sites/bower_components/foundation-sites/assets/images/login_.gif');
}
.send-message
{
 background: url('../lib/foundation-sites/bower_components/foundation-sites/assets/images/send_mass.png');
}
.save-button:hover,
.exit-button:hover,.login-button:active,.login-button:focus,.login-button:hover,.comment-button:hover,.comment-button:focus,.comment-button:active,
,.send-message:hover,.send-message:focus,.send-message:active
{
    outline:transparent;
 background-color:transparent;
}

.exit-button,.save-button,.login-button,.comment-button,.send-message
{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:100% 100% ;
text-align:center;
color: white;
width:100%;
margin:0;
}
.comment-button
{
margin:0 0 1rem;
}
```

This is the implementaion in html page:
this OK:

```html
<button type="button" class="button save-button" id="saveButton" onclick="OKSelectUserDialog()"><fmt:message key="confirm"/></button>
```

this disapear on hover:

```html
  <button   type="button" class="button save-button" onclick="filter();"></button>
```

someone can help me? please......

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.button.save-button:hover {
     opacity: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <button   type="button" class="button save-button" onclick="filter();"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am considering that you are trying to say that you don't want your save button completely transparent on hovering the mous For this you can set opacity value.

For making not transparent at all

Do this

```
.save-button{
       opacity:1;
 }
 <button   type="button" class="button save-button" onclick="filter();">                  
 </button
```

For completely transparent

Set opacity: 0;

Or use any other level between 0 to 1 to make it partially transparent.